# Getting an segmentation fault (core dumped) error in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, struct, error-handling, segmentation-fault

I am trying to build a program which will function as an assembler, it will be getting file name as command line arguments and translate them to machine code.

The program compiles just fine and runs OK with 1 file name, but when I try to run with several, the error appears after the first iteration.

I think there might be something withe the `Clear()` function (which flushes out all the data allocated in the previous iteration), but not sure why. Note that this is partial, but as I said, the program will run unless several files are used.

```
struct symbolStruct { // a structure which is used to absorb info about a tag, its place in memory and related flags
    char *name;
    int place;
    unsigned int isEntry : 1;
    unsigned int isData : 1;
    unsigned int isExternal : 1;
    struct symbolStruct *next;
};

typedef struct { // a structure which is used to absorb info about the operand structure of an instruction line
    unsigned int numOfOperands : 2;
    unsigned int addrMethSou : 2;
    unsigned int addrMethDest : 2;
    unsigned int operation : 4;
    unsigned int extraWords : 2;
    char *firstOperand;
    char *secondOperand;
} OperandType;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int row : WORD_SIZE;
} int15;

struct MachineCode { // a structure which is used to absorb machine code lines, and their location in the assembly file
    unsigned int row : WORD_SIZE;
    unsigned int line;
    OperandType *structure;
    struct MachineCode *next;
};

struct DataCode { // a structure which is used to absorb data and string elements (signed numbers and ascii characters)
    unsigned int row : WORD_SIZE;
    struct DataCode *next;
};

struct Operation { /* the main operation structure, contains pointers to all used lists, the ic and dc counters, the
    current line number which is dealt with and the error flag. */
    unsigned int ic;
    unsigned int dc;
    struct symbolStruct *externHead; // a pointer to a linked list of extern tags used in the assembly file, and their locations
    struct symbolStruct *symbolHead; // a pointer to a linked list of all tags
    struct DataCode *dataHead; // a pointer to a linked list of all data/string elements
    struct MachineCode *machineHead; // a pointer to a linked list of all machine code rows
    int linenumber;
    unsigned int errorflag : 1; // raised in case of an error which triggered a warning
};

#include "header.h"

void FirstRun(struct Operation*, char *);
void DataUpdate(struct symbolStruct*,int);
void SecondRun(struct Operation *, char *);
void Clear(struct Operation *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    struct Operation programCore = {0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0};
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        char *fn = argv[i];
        FirstRun(&programCore,fn);
        DataUpdate(programCore.symbolHead,programCore.ic+INSTRUCTION_OFFSET);
        SecondRun(&programCore,fn);
        Clear(&programCore);
        programCore.symbolHead = programCore.externHead = programCore.dataHead = programCore.machineHead = NULL;
    }
    if(argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"No files selected.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

/*Used to empty the linked lists and allocated memory after the program has finished one iteration. */
void Clear(struct Operation *programCore) { 
    /*f(pointer name) is there to hold a pointer to the allocated memory which is about to be flushed. */
    struct MachineCode *machineHead = programCore->machineHead, *fMachineHead; 
    struct DataCode *dataHead = programCore->dataHead, *fDataHead; 
        struct symbolStruct *externHead = programCore->externHead, *fExternHead;
    struct symbolStruct *symbolHead = programCore->symbolHead, *fSymbolHead;
    while(machineHead != NULL) {
            fMachineHead = machineHead;
        machineHead = machineHead->next;
        if(fMachineHead->structure != NULL) {
            if(fMachineHead->structure->numOfOperands == 2)
                free(fMachineHead->structure->secondOperand);
            if(fMachineHead->structure->numOfOperands > 0)
                free(fMachineHead->structure->firstOperand);
            free(fMachineHead->structure);
        }
        free(fMachineHead);
    }
    while(dataHead != NULL) {
        fDataHead = dataHead;
        dataHead = dataHead->next;
        free(fDataHead);
    }
    while(externHead != NULL) {
        fExternHead = externHead;
        externHead = externHead->next;
        free(fExternHead->name);
        free(fExternHead);
    }
    while(symbolHead != NULL) {
        fSymbolHead = symbolHead;
        symbolHead = symbolHead->next;
        free(fSymbolHead->name);
        free(fSymbolHead);
    }
    programCore->ic = programCore->dc = programCore->linenumber = programCore->errorflag = 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't said where your code crashes - run it in a debugger and you'll see on what line it happens. Might also show you what you need to fix too.

Comment: [off-topic] Personally, I would use (variable sized) arrays, and not Linked Lists for the tables.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: while the 'implicit conversion' feature may save the code, it should not be relied upon.  There is a major difference in the meaning between NULL and 0 (although the bit values may be the same.

Comment: When there is a problem with the command line parameters, (For instance there are none) The the code should output a `USAGE` statement to `stderr`,  similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <srcFileName1> [[srcFileNameN]]\n", argv[0] );`  Such a statement is usually followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the macro: `WORD_SIZE` not defined within the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not free and nullifying the linked lists in the context struct (`programCore`). I suspect you are then using pointers to freed memory blocks.

This line only copies the pointer:

```
struct MachineCode *machineHead = programCore->machineHead;
```

The while() loop is not clearing `programCore->machineHead`

To fix it, run directly on the head:

```
while(programCore->machineHead != NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If i'll do so, doesn't it clears only the head, and not the nodes after it? How do I make sure the entire list is cleared, and the head nullified?

Comment: I also want to make sure both the strings firstOperand and secondOperand are refering to are cleared.

Comment: I think the program is indeed the fact that I am not nullifying the heads, as later on I have a function that checks if the head == NULL, and allocates memory to a new node if that's the case.

Comment: problem* goddamnit

Answer (score 0):

Well, by getting rid of

```
   if(fMachineHead->structure->numOfOperands == 2)
         free(fMachineHead->structure->secondOperand);
   if(fMachineHead->structure->numOfOperands > 0)
         free(fMachineHead->structure->firstOperand);
```

I have managed to solve the error, but now I am getting a new one -

```
main.c:242:13: error: request for member ‘symbolHead’ in something not a structure or union
main.c:242:38: error: request for member ‘externHead’ in something not a structure or union
main.c:243:13: error: request for member ‘dataHead’ in something not a structure or union
main.c:244:13: error: request for member ‘machineHead’ in something not a structure or union
```

Referring to the next line -

```
        programCore.symbolHead = programCore.externHead = programCore.dataHead = programCore.machineHead = NULL;
```

Is there a problem with the way I wrote that? (Obviously yes, but I just don't see it).

Comment: the problem is some those fields are `unsigned int` and some are `int`  and the operations are performed from right to left, so some `unsigned int` values are being assigned from `int` values.  Suggest writing each assignment as a separate statement.

Comment: the problem is that `protramCore` is a pointer, so must use `->` rather than `.`  ALSO, each of those pointers is a different type and the operations are performed from right to left, and different types of pointers cannot be assigned.  Suggest writing each assignment as a separate statement.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the clear() function again and it seems to be working fine now.

```
    /*Used to empty the linked lists and allocated memory after the program has finished one iteration. */
void Clear(struct Operation *programCore) { 
    /*f(pointer name) is there to hold a pointer to the allocated memory which is about to be flushed. */
    struct MachineCode *machineRowPointer = programCore->machineHead, *fMachineRow; 
    struct DataCode *dataRowPointer = programCore->dataHead, *fDataRow; 
        struct symbolStruct *externSymbolPointer = programCore->externHead, *fExtern;
    struct symbolStruct *symbolPointer = programCore->symbolHead, *fSymbol;
    if(machineRowPointer != NULL) {
        while(machineRowPointer != NULL) {
            if(machineRowPointer->structure != NULL)
                free(machineRowPointer->structure);
            fMachineRow = machineRowPointer;
            machineRowPointer = machineRowPointer->next;
            free(fMachineRow);
        }
        programCore->machineHead = NULL;
    }
    if(dataRowPointer != NULL) {
        while(dataRowPointer != NULL) {
            fDataRow = dataRowPointer;
            dataRowPointer = dataRowPointer->next;
            free(fDataRow);
        }
        programCore->dataHead = NULL;
    }
    if(externSymbolPointer != NULL) {
        while(externSymbolPointer != NULL) {
            fExtern = externSymbolPointer;
            externSymbolPointer = externSymbolPointer->next;
            free(fExtern->name);
            free(fExtern);
        }
        programCore->externHead = NULL;
    }
    if(symbolPointer != NULL) {
        while(symbolPointer != NULL) {
            fSymbol = symbolPointer;
            symbolPointer = symbolPointer->next;
            free(fSymbol->name);
            free(fSymbol);
        }
        programCore->symbolHead = NULL;
    }
    programCore->ic = programCore->dc = programCore->linenumber = programCore->errorflag = 0;
}
```